# How do I compile a Haskell Mach-O executable that exports a symbol?

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, ffi

How do I compile a Haskell *executable* (not a library) using GHC >=8.2.1 (preferably on 8.6.*) on macOS 10.14.5 that successfully `foreign export`s a function (i.e. exposes it as a public symbol in the binary)? This works in GHC 8.0.2 but not in later versions.

I've tried this on ghc 8.0.2 (via stack), 8.2.2 (via both nix and stack), 8.4.4 (via both nix and stack), and 8.6.4 (via both nix and stack). Only 8.0.2 works. I know that 8.2 introduced this change: `GHC will now use ld.gold or ld.lld instead of the system’s default`ld`, if available.` But I am unclear whether 8.0.2 would use a different 'system default' ld in the first place (darwin's ld as opposed to llvm's lld?). I know of ghc's `-pgml [ld-program-here]` option to set the linker but I haven't been able to manually set it to anything that has successfully compiled and linked anything to test further.

I have this file `Main.hs`:

```hs
module Main where

import Foreign.C

foreign export ccall "my_square" my_square :: CInt -> CInt

my_square :: CInt -> CInt
my_square x = x * x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "FFI Test"
```

With ghc 8.0.2:

```
> rm Main.hi Main.o && ghc-8.0.2 Main.hs && nm -g Main | grep my_square
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
[some apparently unrelated clang warnings]
Linking Main ...
[further clang warnings]
2544:0000000100001260 T _my_square
```

With ghc 8.6.4, the symbol doesn't seem to be exported, so future attempts to link another program with this symbol fail.

```
> rm Main.hi Main.o && ghc-8.6.4 Main.hs && nm -g Main | grep my_square
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
```

Comment: The symbol is not exported with GHC 8.0.2, either. GHC exports `_my_square` from `Main.o`, always. When the `Main` executable is linked, that symbol gets added to it. Newer GHC passes `-dead-strip` to the linker, which cleans the non-exported `_my_square` symbol out. Older GHC doesn't, so it leaves the symbol there, even though it isn't correctly exported. GHC appears to be hardcoded to export no symbols from an executable. Perhaps file a bug to change that? Any answer to this question will probably be uglier than having GHC do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off what I said in my comment, neither version of GHC you tested actually exports `_my_square` from `Main`. Instead, they export `_my_square` from `Main.o` (this is why you can use `ghc` to compile and link a `.c` file that uses `my_square`). When `Main.o` is linked into the final `Main` executable, neither GHC tells the linker to export `_my_square`. GHC 8.6.4 (and, I think, since 8.2) tells the linker to strip unused, unexported symbols, so  `_my_square` evaporates. GHC 8.0.2 does not, leaving `_my_sqaure` in the `Main` executable purely by accident.

You can tell GHC to tell the linker to keep the symbol. The linker option for this is `-exported_symbol <symbol>`. My GHC actually invokes the linker through `gcc`, so I have to wrap those two arguments with `-Wl`. For whatever reason, passing that option to the GHC actually compiling `Main.hs` causes an error; you have to make `Main.o` with one bare GHC invocation and then call GHC again to link it into `Main`, this time with the linker options. Maybe this is peculiar to my system—you may experiment to find a better way.

```
$ ghc -c Main.hs
# Makes Main.hi Main.o Main_stub.h
$ ghc -optl-Wl,-exported_symbol -optl-Wl,_my_square Main.o -o Main
# Makes Main
$ objdump -t Main | grep _my_square
0000000100000dc0 g     F __TEXT,__text  _my_square
```

I would still recommend filing a GHC issue to make this easier.